# I want to connect android to my nao it is version V4 or 1.14.5

Tags: android, connection, nao-robot, choregraphe

I want to connect android  to my nao , it is version V4 or 1.14.5 and I do not find library to use it for android that is appropriate for this version , I tried with qimessage  library but the robot does not work.

Answer (score 0):

To use the QiMessaging library, you will need to upgrade your robot to NAOqi 2.1 - it didn't exist in 1.14.

Comment: Ok there is any another librray can connect nao 1.14.5 to Android ??

Comment: Well, you could always build something with sockets.